# what is the difference between selenium.click and driver.click

Tags: selenium, junit4

I have recorded a scenario in Selenium IDE and exported it as a Junit4 Webdriver backed code.

There is a command which uses selenium object and the same thing could be done by driver object.
So I am not able to understand which one to use and when

E.g :
  selenium.click("id=gen_info") can also be implemented by

driver.findElement(By.id("gen_info")).click();

Yes I do have a option to have a driver object of specific web browser but then the same thing could be done by using selenium object also.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by selenium click u mean something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
```

WebDriverBackedSelenium allows those who have test suites using the Selenium-RC to migrate to WebDriver. However it doesn't implement all methods.

In this particular case it should work the same, though WebDriverBacked may be slower